# Can I use this query in the entity 4.0 framework?

Tags: linq, t-sql, frameworks, entity

I'm needing some syntax help with the following query please? I'd like to use an equivalent in the entity framework but I'm unsure of the syntax.

Can someone help me format this to work with the entity framework?

Thanks in advance.

```
    Select * from (
    SELECT [Member]
      ,[MemberGroup],
    (SELECT [text]
  FROM [umbracoNode]where [id] = [Member]) As MemberName,
(SELECT [text]
  FROM [umbracoNode]where [id] = [MemberGroup]) As GroupName
  FROM [cmsMember2MemberGroup]
) UG
where UG.MemberName is not null
order by UG.MemberName,
UG.GroupName
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
var query =
    from x in db.cmsMember2MemberGroup
    join y in db.umbracoNode on x.Member equals y.id
    let MemberName = y.text
    where MemberName != null
    join z in db.umbracoNode on x.MemberGroup equals z.id
    let GroupName = z.text
    orderby new { MemberName, GroupName }
    select new
    {
        x.Member,
        x.MemberGroup,
        MemberName,
        GroupName,
    };
```

Comment: @user686483 - No worries. I see that you're a new user. Now you should mark this as the answer and maybe give it an upvote.

Answer (score 0):

Is there a particular reason that this query is in this format?

Why are there not use of joins?

Need to really understand what you want here first and get into better sql before going to linq.

Comment: Team me then, oh grand master Cubicle Jockey.